# How to configure single nginx ingress with letsencrypt and multiple bitnami wordpress containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx, ingress, wordpress

I'm using bitnami/wordpress helm chart to create many websites which should run on different domains. I'd like to auto secure them and use a single ingress to route traffic. I'm using this tutorial https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/secure-wordpress-kubernetes-managed-database-ssl-upgrades/ to create ingress nginx controller + letsencrypt.

Routing works fine, but the ssl works only for the first created wordpress container/domain and those after it are not secured. I can't figure out why? k8s v1.19.10-gke.1600 helm 3.6.0

Let's say i have sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com and i have two  sub1.domain.com.values.yaml and sub2.domain.com.values.yamlfiles to customize bitnami/wordpress helm chart

Config is as follows:
sub1.domain.com.values.yaml:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  certManager: true
  hostname: sub1.domain.com
  extraTls:
  - hosts:
      - sub1.domain.com
    secretName: wordpress.local-tls
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
```

sub2.domain.com.values.yaml:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  certManager: true
  hostname: sub2.domain.com
  extraTls:
  - hosts:
      - sub2.domain.com
    secretName: wordpress.local-tls
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
```

I apply them with:

```
helm install sub1 bitnami/wordpress -f sub1.domain.com.values.yaml
helm install sub2 bitnami/wordpress -f sub2.domain.com.values.yaml
```

Buth are accessible via browser, but only sub1.domain.com is with valid ssl cert, sub2 is with kubernetes fake cert.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same TLS secret will not be mapped to two ingress at the same time within a namespace.It will map to the first deployed ingress. Create the same secret with a different name and map it to the other ingress for it to work.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. It's up to bitnami to handle that. By not specifying the name of the tls secret it creates it with different names, so it worked.